# How to generate BuildConfig.DEBUG?

Tags: android

Using an IDE like Eclipse, IntelliJ, Studio, the class BuildConfig is auto generated in the gen folder. But what if you are using makefiles; not using an IDE? Can any of the build tools auto generate this?

When I tried to add android:debuggable attribute to my AndroidManifest.xml
as described in the link below, I got a compiler error that it could not find the field.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html

> Turn off logging and debugging
>
> Make sure you deactivate logging and disable the debugging option
>   before you build your application for release. You can deactivate
>   logging by removing calls to Log methods in your source files. You can
>   **disable debugging by removing the android:debuggable attribute** from
>   **the  tag in your manifest file, or by setting the**
>   **android:debuggable attribute to false in your manifest file**. Also,
>   remove any log files or static test files that were created in your
>   project.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the build tools from command can generate `BuildConfig.java` file for you.

1.create project in command

```
$ android create project -t android-21 -p . -n AntTest --package com.example.test -a StartupActivity
```

2.create the makefile

```
release:
    @ant release

debug:
    @ant debug

release_install:
    @ant installr

debug_install:
    @ant installd
```

3.you can reference `BuildConfig` in your code, the build tool ant will generate `BuildConfig.java` for you.

After you invoke any command to build the project, you will see the file is generated `gen/com/example/test/BuildConfig.java`.

**Additional information**

`BuildConfig.java` is handled and generated by ant. We can see it from `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/ant/build.xml`.

```
<echo level="info">----------</echo>
<echo level="info">Handling BuildConfig class...</echo>
<buildconfig
        genFolder="${gen.absolute.dir}"
        package="${project.app.package}"
        buildType="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
        previousBuildType="${build.last.is.packaging.debug}"/>
```

Comment: how does ant know about BuildConfig? it is unclear to me

Comment: The file `BuildConfig.java` is generated by ant. Ant knows it of cause.

Comment: unless there is an Ant task created to do this, I don't think so.